# asp.net website, authentication when url is with www and without www

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting

I have website built with ASP.NET MVC. The website has SSL so I have a redirection from any call to https.

However, when a user is loging in, I can have two tabs, one with the website open using www and the other is not using www: https://example.com and https://www.example.com.

If a user is logged in using one form of url I would expect the browser to notice that the user is logged in even if the other tab uses the other form of url. But this is not the case. The browser (Chrome on Windows) does not recognizes that the user is logged in.

How can I handle that so the user will appear logged in using any form of url?

Comment: how is your authentication setup?

Comment: @Alex The basic authentication coming with ASP.NET MVC package. Nothing special. I'm still puzzled by this because I would expect that the same domain with and without WWW will be authenticated by the system. However I used Neil's solution and it works. Since its looks even nicer this way I'll just drop inquiring more into this. However, if somebody will come here and could shed some light on the reasons why the authentication doesn't work the way I expected I'd love to read that. Thank you Alex and Neil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should setup a 301 redirect from `www.example` to `example` or `example` to `www.example` so your users only use the application from a single domain. Many websites (Facebook, Reddit, and StackOverflow to name a few) use a 301 redirect from www.domain.com to domain.com.

[image]